# Почему вылезает ошибка сегментации C++ (signal: segmentation fault (core dumped))

Tags: c++, память, segmentation-fault

```
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;

int main(){
    ll n;
    cin >> n;
    ll arr1[100000][100000];
    
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
            arr1[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    
    ll tmp;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cin >> tmp;
        arr1[i][tmp-1] = 1;
        cout << tmp-1 << " " << i << " " << n << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
            cout << arr1[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    ll counter = 0;
    cout << endl;
    for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
        counter = 0;
        for(int i = n-1; i>=0; i--){
            if(arr1[i][j]==1){
                cout << counter+1;
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Подозреваю что дело в массиве arr1

Comment: не хватает памяти в стеке. решается только выделением памяти с помощью **new**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
long long arr1[100000][100000];
```

Итого 8*10000000000 байт ≈ 74.5 Гигабайт

Как вы собираетесь выделить такое большое количество памяти? даже в 64-разрядном коде столько памяти — никакой своп не поможет...

Visual C++ 2019 такой код просто компилировать отказывается.

Что-то типа этого можно — для реальных `n`, конечно:

```
ll n;
cin >> n;
ll ** arr1 = new ll*[n];
for(ll i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    arr1[i] = new ll[n];
```